# Confused about Big-O notation

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

**I am new to Big-O notation. While reading I came across an example :**

```
Qus : Find upper bound for f(n) = n^2 + 1

Sol : n^2 + 1 <= 2n^2  for all n >= 1

so f(n) = O(n^2) with c = 2 and n0 = 1
```

**after this I came across second example :**

```
Qus : Find upper bound for f(n) = n

Sol : n <= n^2 for all n >=1

so f(n) = O(n^2) with c = 1 and n0 = 1
```

**I am confused that according to Big-O notation if f(n) = n then f(n) = O(n) so I want to know if the following solution to second example is right ?**

```
Sol : n <= 2n for all n >=1

so f(n) = O(n) with c = 2 and n0 = 1
```

Comment: yes that's right. the second example is also not wrong and f(n) is also O(n^3).

Comment: Ok if we are considering the tightest upper bound then which solution would be appropriate ?

Comment: Tight bound, Theta, is a function with which you can show both upper and lower bounds. In your case you can show f(n) is also Omega(n) and thus prove it's Theta(n). But just considering all functions above for upper bound I think they are all correct without any difference.

Comment: Isn't f(n) = O(n) more close to tight upper bound ?

Comment: It is more close, but the definition of big-oh does not care about distance. If you are interested in tightness you should use Theta.

Comment: I see no relation to asymptotic complexity in this particular question, just plain math - shouldn't it be somewhere at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

A complement of those comments:

Start from the definition of Big O
we can say that f(x) is O(g(x)) if and only if there exist a positive 
number B and a non-negative real number b such that:

`|f(x)|is less or equal to B|g(x)| for all numbers x that large than b`

Therefore, we could say that for `f(n)=n f(n)=O(n)`,
since there exists a number B (for instance "2") make that `n<=Bn`.
(n<=2n, for all the n=>0)